# Sequential execution on Cassandra.AsyncClient

Tags: java, asynchronous, cassandra, thrift

I am trying to use Cassandra.AsyncClient for my application, I have two calls .set_keyspace and .system_add_column_family. A snippet goes like this,

```
Callback<Cassandra.AsyncClient.set_keyspace_call> c0 = new Callback<Cassandra.AsyncClient.set_keyspace_call>();
client.set_keyspace(this.keyspace, c0);
Callback<Cassandra.AsyncClient.system_add_column_family_call> c1 = new Callback<Cassandra.AsyncClient.system_add_column_family_call>();
client.system_add_column_family(cfDef, c1);
```

and I got:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client is currently executing another method: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$AsyncClient$set_keyspace_call
```

Callback is an implementation of AsyncMethodCallback, and it doesn't do anything except printout the result. I happen to get around it by making the thread wait in between the calls

```
long _t = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - _t < 500) {};
```

but is there a cleaner, more elegant way of doing this, or some kind of twist I can do with the AsyncMethodCallback? I read on some blog to do:

```
while (cb.getResult() == null) {  }
```

getResult is to save the result on the callback, but this also seems inelegant.

Comment: The async client was designed for the data path, not for schema changes.  One reason is that schema changes often need to be ordered - you will need a keyspace to be created before you create the column family.

Comment: but even if I want to use it for insert, i still need to run .set_keyspace on the client first? no?